# OpenSky Network REST API, response filtered by location

Tags: rest

Just starting out using the OpenSky Network REST API and am looking for a way to capture aircraft in a particular location.  I can see an api/states/all endpoint, and a way to filter results by receiver using serials=nnn (although the Receiver Availability page only gives the serial number, not the location of the receivers), but is it possible to only fetch aircraft state vectors that match a requested location/range? It could be done in the client of course, but this would help to minimise the API traffic

Answer (score 2):

A few months ago, a latitude and logitude filter for requests to `/api/states/all` was added to the OpenSky API:

[image]

Please refer to the [API Documentation](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html#request) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the OpenSky Network developers.

<strike>Filtering for a particular area is not possible at the moment. We are planning to implement a bounding box filter, but it won't be available before autumn 2017.</strike>

**Update August 2018** (a bit late, because I nearly forgot about this post)

In the meantime filtering by location is possible. You can define a bounding box using `lamin`, `lomin`, `lomax` und `lamax` (`lo` = longitude, `la` = latitude). Here is an example:

`https://opensky-network.org/api/states/all?lamin=45.8389&lomin=5.9962&lamax=47.8229&lomax=10.5226`

For more detailed information, have a look at the [API documentation](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html)